# Custom email to case: Inline images not visible in email object

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, email2case

We have enabled custom email to case for our client. When an email is sent with inline image, the images are added as a attachment under Attachment/ Notes of Email message object. But I'm unable to see it from the email message body in salesforce. Please see the below image for reference.

While creating the email object this is how I assign html body.

```
private static void handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email) {
        
        EmailMessage obEmail = new EmailMessage();
        Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dml.allowFieldTruncation = true;
        
        try {
            obEmail.HtmlBody = email.htmlBody;
            /*rest of the assignments and code*/
        }
}
```

How do I show the image in the salesforce instead of just the file name. Any help is appreciated.